What does tilt mean here?
https://x.com/Nate_Cohn/status/1845179426948120925 says "Imagine, for instance, if you had a poll of one MAGA hat-wearer and one Biden stan. If you weighted them by past vote, you'd always get the 2020 election result.
The catch is that these highly engaged, loyal voters tilt Democratic - see, special elections etc."
What does tilt mean here?
Which sense of tilt in online Merriam Webster dictionary https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tilt applies here?

It's the definition that says "to incline, tend, or become drawn toward an opinion, course of action, or one side of a controversy"

Where is the word tilt in your post?

@Lambie these highly engaged, loyal voters tilt Democratic

@MichaelHarvey Thanks. I guess I missed it...

@Lambie - it's only a little word. I have noticed people using 'lean' the same way e.g. a person or a newspaper is 'left (or right) leaning'. It seems odd. When something leans it might go back to being upright again. I am 'left' politically but it's not a lean or a tilt, it's where I stand.

@MichaelHarvey I missed reading it on the page, innit.  Sure, lean, tilt,

I might say 'I liked the look of the chocolate ice-cream, but now I am inclining towards the raspberry parfait'.

It means that the have a tendency to support Democrats, but not necessarily an overwhelming one.
As for which definition in the online dictionary, I would go with:
tilt:

b : to incline, tend, or become drawn toward an opinion, course of
action, or one side of a controversy

Merriam Webster
